# Show that f is one-one

Tags: calculus, functions

I'm given this problem of:

Show that $f$ is one-one

$$f(x) = (\ln x - 1)(\ln x - 2), \quad 0 < x < 4$$

Now I know that to show it is one-one, I just have to differentiate the $f(x)$. But why is it that expanding the function would yield me a wrong answer?

e.g. Rather than having to use chain rule for the above $f(x)$ I expand, and then use product rule to get $(2\ln x -2x -3)/x$. However the answer is wrong. So my question is, is it wrong to expand when given a function like that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$(\ln x)^2\ne\ln x^2$. In particular, $(\ln x)^2\ne 2\ln x$.

Comment: Great, thanks! I've noticed my mistake. Been doing math the whole morning goodness.

Comment: We do silly things from time to time.